# ASP.NET C# - display photos dynamically and list them with boostrap

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on my ASP.NET project. I had a static website, now I'm converting it to a dynamic website.

This is the markup I used for displaying photos on my static website:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 galeri-item filter-app">
<div class="galeri-wrap">
<img src="img/galeri/resim1.jpeg" class="img-fluid">
</div>
</div>
```

This is the look of my static website with the code I use (already indicated the code upside):

[image]

Now I'm working on my dynamic website. I display my images from folder in backend like this

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/img/galeri/"));
            List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();

            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                files.Add(new ListItem(fileName, "~/img/galeri/" + fileName));
            }

            dtlist.DataSource = files;
            dtlist.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I display my photos at frontend with this code. I tried to add my bootstrap code as well but it just listed them all in a column. How can I fix this? I would be glad if you can help me.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtlist" runat="server" >
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat="server"  CssClass="row galeri-container col-lg-4 col-md-6 galeri-item filter-app galeri-wrap img-fluid"/>
  <span>-</span>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:DataList>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If bootstrap columns exceeds 12 , it will wrap into new row

```
<div class="row">
<asp:DataList ID="dtlist" runat="server" >
<ItemTemplate>
    <div id="listItem" class="col-md-4">
        <asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat="server" />
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

</div>
```

Comment: I want to have exactly the same display as my static webiste. "  <div id="listItem" class="col-md-4">" not gives the same display as my static website.

Comment: For detail layout, you should use/replace your css from static websites, my answer is just to illustrate three columns display from data.

Comment: The problem is I can not apply my css codes one by one at photos, css code applies to all photos called by the code whch is located at backend thats why i can not seperate them.

Comment: If your code is  like below, 
     <asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat="server"  CssClass="row galeri-container col-lg-4 col-md-6 galeri-item filter-app galeri-wrap img-fluid"/>

It should be changed to  
    CssClass ="img-fluid" only, bcos only the image related css attributes should be applied to.

These attributes (row galeri-container)  should be in front-end div wrapping the image.

Comment: I tried to seperate them as you said but still, i can not get the same display.